# Database inspector gone after Arctic Fox update

Tags: android, database, android-studio

After updating to Arctic Fox, I'm missing the cool `Database Inspector` which was a godsend when they introduced it. I don't see it in the footer anymore, I don't see it in the 'View -> Tool Window' menu, it's just gone! It all worked just fine up to the point where I updated Studio.

Any idea what I might have done to cause this? I initially assumed it was officially removed or replaced, but I don't see anything  to that effect.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's under App Inspection now.

[image]

Comment: D'oh! How did I miss that, I actually looked at it, thanks!!!